# How To Transfer Logs From Fortigate (VM) to ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, virtual-machine, kibana, elk, fortigate

So I am new to this, i installed the elk and FORTIGATE but don't know how to transfer the logs over IP..
thank you

i searched over internet but not able to find any correct way.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/enotspe/fortinet-2-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable syslog to logstash: [here](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/56/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-logging-reporting/logs.htm)
And use [fortigate](https://gist.github.com/onodai145/4a613ae068665c2d618c163c55313cfd) filters for logstash.